# INSERT INTO with subquery and text value at once

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to put data to employees table by inserting data in this way:

```
insert into employees(lastName, firstName, extension, email, officeCode, jobTitle)
    select contactLastName, contactFirstName 
    from customers 
    where country like 'usa'
    union all
    select officeCode 
    from offices 
    where country like 'USA' 
    limit 1;
```

But extension, email and JobTitle doesn't exist in customers and offices.
Is there any option to make INSERT INTO with subquery and text values for those 3 columns?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: please post data a text / tables and not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able exclude the columns you don't want as long as they aren't required fields and then you can join to your offices table.

```
INSERT INTO employees (lastName, firstName, officeCode, extension, email, jobTitle)
SELECT contactLastName, contactFirstName, officeCode, ‘999’, ‘email@email.com’, ‘Manager’
FROM   customers
       LEFT JOIN offices ON offices.country = customers.country
WHERE  customers.country = 'USA'
```

Comment: I understand this solution but I have to add there other values. As I can see you insert only into 3 columns of my table.

Comment: What do you expect the missing values to be then?

Comment: I need to insert extension, email and JobTitle and job title is the most important to me the other values can be dummy

Comment: Those fields do not exist on your customers table. Are you wanting to manually set them all to the same value when inserting?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i want

Comment: Can just add them to the end of the select then. Updated answer

Comment: Thanks for help <3